# Error get to show sub-categories in the Categories Dropdown list

Tags: laravel

in my code,i want to show **category** and **sub catagory** under the **Category** in the **Products table**.

Here is my **categories table**

1.

```
 public function up() { Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('parent_id'); //sub category id
    $table->string('name');  
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Here is my **products table**

2.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->string('product_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is my **Category Model**

**3.Category.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model { protected $guarded=[];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Here is my **Product Model**

**4.Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->hasone('class::Category');
    }

}
```

Now here is my **ProductsController.php**

**5.ProductsController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
     public function addproduct(Request $request){
         $product=New Product();
         $product->category_id=$request['category_id'];
         $product->product_name=$request['product_name'];
         $product->save();
         return back()->with('success','product Upload Successfully!');
         }
}
```

Here is my **addproduct.blade.php** file

**6.addproduct.blade.ph**p

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{route('add.product')}}" name="add_product" id="add_product" novalidate="novalidate">
                                @csrf

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">main Category </label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select name="category_id" id="category_id" style="width:220px;">

                                            @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
                                                <option value="{{$cat->id}}" >{{ $cat->parent()->name ? $cat->parent()->name . ' -- ' : '' }}{{$cat->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

7. I want to data like this

   **Shoe** 
    *--casual shoe*
    *--formal shoe* 
   **Mobile** 
     *--Android Mobile* 
     *--iphone*
   **Tshirt**
    *--casual T-shirt*
    *--Formal T-shirt*

thats why i use this code **addproduct.blade.php**

```
@foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
<option value="{{$cat->id}}" >{{ $cat->parent()->name ? $cat->parent()->name . ' -- ' : '' }}{{$cat->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

but when i apply this code i get **error** like this:-

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: F:\laragon\www\flipcart\resources\views\admin\products\addproduct.blade.php)
```

Comment: You might have to set the parent relation with a custom key.  return $this->belongsTo('Parent', 'parent_id');

Comment: Class 'Parent' not found (View: F:\laragon\www\flipcart\resources\views\admin\products\addproduct.blade.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your relationship in Category model as below and try,

```
public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','parent_id','id');
}
```

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: F:\laragon\www\flipcart\resources\views\admin\products\addproduct.blade.php)

Comment: can you change it as `$cat->parent->name`

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: F:\laragon\www\flipcart\resources\views\admin\products\product.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (0)